# unable to import css file in my react js file, i have installed the css loader but dont know how to include it in my webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I'm a second year cs student and new to MERN, i have downloaded a mern boilerplate to build a login system but im unable to import css file onto the main home.js page.
i need help including the css file in home.js (css file is in the components folder, same as home.js).

**webpack.config.js**

```
 switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'prod':
  case 'production':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod');
    break;

  case 'dev':
  case 'development':
  default:
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev');
}
```

**app.css**

```
*{
    background-color: ivory;
}
```

```
**error message**
ERROR in ./client/app/components/app.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> *{
|     background-color: ivory;
| }
 @ ./client/app/components/Home/Home.js 26:0-16
 @ ./client/app/index.js
 @ multi ./client/app/index.js webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add postcss loader

You can check this documentation.

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/postcss-loader/#getting-started

UPDATE:
I am sharing my webpack code hope you get some idea.

file name: postcss.config.css

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

file name: webpack.config.js

```
'use strict';

const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

let config = {
    entry: {
        main: [
            './_devapp/app.js',
            './_devapp/css/app.css'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets', 'bundle'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|tsx|ts)$/,
                exclude:path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                            '@babel/preset-react',
                            '@babel/preset-typescript'
                        ],
                        plugins : [
                            ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
                            '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
                            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { "loose": true }]
                        ]
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                test: /.(png|woff(2)?|eot|ttf|svg|gif)(\?[a-z0-9=\.]+)?$/,
                use: [
                {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '../css/[hash].[ext]'
                    }
                }
                ]
            },
            {
                test : /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin(path.join('..', 'css', 'app.css')),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            '__DEV__' : JSON.stringify(true),
            '__API_HOST__' : JSON.stringify('http://localhost/my_works/react/invoice/php-react-setup/'),
        }),
    ],
      
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false,
            compress: {
                sequences: true,
                conditionals: true,
                booleans: true,
                if_return: true,
                join_vars: true,
                drop_console: true
            },
            output: {
                comments: false
            },
            minimize: true
        })
    );
}

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: according to the website mentioned, postcss loader has to be installed and added in webpack.config.js, however it isn't clear where to add. webpack.config.js in my folder is very different from webpack config in a react app, hence the confusion